# iron-router map without layoutTemplate

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have iron-router with `layoutTemplate` in configuration. For my requirement i need to include some iframe element without rendering layoutTemplate.

```
//My configuration
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

//My routes
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.route('Iframe', {path: '/iframe'}); //this particular path should render without layoutTemplate.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add layout name in route map.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('Iframe', {path: '/iframe',layoutTemplate:'Iframe'});
});
```